# Executable under GDB invokes different embedded Python

Tags: python, linux, gdb, python-c-api

I have code that embeds Python. That embedded Python uses NumPy and hence, I need to explicitly load `libpython`, to make NumPy work.

The driving code is in C++ (tests in Google Test). There is a bug somewhere, and I try to use `gdb` for debugging. However, something strange happens as embedded versions are different, when I simply run the executable and when I run the executable under `gdb`.

I find the path to `libpython` by instantiating `sysconfig` module under the initialized embedded Python and then using `sysconfig.get_config_var("LIBDIR")`.

I log the found path to the `libpython` hen I simply run the executable:

```
Path to libpython is /home/dima/.conda/envs/um02-open-interfaces/lib
```

When I run the same executable under `gdb`:

```
Path to libpython is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.11/lib
```

How to stop `gdb` from changing environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to stop gdb from changing environment?

GDB doesn't change the environment *on its own*. However, it *does* invoke your `$SHELL`, and if you have `~/.bashrc` or similar file changing the environment, than these changes will affect any process invoked by the GDB `run` command.

You can confirm whether that is happening by running `$SHELL -c /path/to/your/program`. If it prints the wrong path to `libpython`, this is likely the root cause.

The fix is to make `.bashrc` change the environment *only* for [interactive](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html) shells.

You could also disable the intermediate `$SHELL` using GDB `set startup-with-shell off` ([documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Starting.html)).